# python: list comprehensive scoping issue, how to include variable created outside of `[]`?

Tags: python

```
x = 2
[i+x for i in range(3)]
```

errors with `*** NameError: name 'x' is not defined`

How do I make `x` available for use in list comprehension?

[image]

This happens when I test it within a function.

Comment: This works fine on my PC after I add `]` in the end,.

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works for me, I just added the missing closing square bracket ] on the list comprehension.

If you are using it in a function, are you passing x in properly?

```
def test(x):
    return [i+x for i in range(3)]
test(2)
```

ouptut:

```
[2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it worked for me try this one

```py
    x = 2
    k=[i+x for i in range(3)]
    print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

x =2

[i+x for i in range(3)]

OUTPUT : [2, 3, 4]

This should work.
You can use outside variable inside list comprehension. Might be issue is with list comprehension not ends with ']'.

Answer (score 0):

The code goes correctly for me.

```
>>>x =2
>>> [i+x for i in range(3)]
[2, 3, 4]
```

Or

```
>>>x =2
>>> k=[i+x for i in range(3)]
>>> k
[2, 3, 4]
```